# Error when setting default page in a multisite sitecore extranet

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have a multisite configuration, and one of the sites is a secure extranet

- Not logged users (anonymous) will be redirected to the login page
- the default page is home

So my configuration reads like this

```
<site name="aodextranet" hostName="preprod.aodextranet.org" virtualFolder="/" 
      physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content/Sites/Extranet" 
      startItem="/Home" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true"
      cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" 
      viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB"
      enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true"
      disableClientData="false" loginPage="/login.aspx" />
```

- if I go to mysite/home I'm redirected to the login page as expected
- but if I only write mysite without the explicit reference to the home
  page the sites throws an error: no layout page.

If /home is the start item in the configuration file, I should go to home and then redirected to the login page. I've tried upper and lower case without success

This is a screen cast
http://screencast.com/t/aiF0BNk4lWr

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: You say you have a multi-site configuration, but there is only one site configuration posted. The problem might be caused by another site configuration. Could you share those too (only the non-default ones)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! 
After creating a new site in a multisite configuration, you have to publish the whole site... I was publishing only the site node plus the templates. After running the full publish, the site is behaving as expected.

Comment: That one was too obvious for me to ask ;)

Comment: usually the obvious are the hardest :)

Answer (score 1):

The sitecore item `/sitecore/content/Sites/Extranet/Home` is the item that is shown when you navigate in the browser to `preprod.aodextranet.org`.
This item should have a layout and sublayouts/renderings added to the presentation tab.
Looking at your configuration it seems that you have misconfigured your site-definition or did not add the presentation elements to the item /extranet/home.

Comment: you have a point there which I somehow overlooked ;) , either way you are  opening (or it should open) the same page but somehow you seem to be redirected to item "/" if i inspect the url of the errorpage. Do you use something like a UrlRewrite module or a custom itemresolver pipeline?